# Mongo morphia plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails

While building my grails application through ant, i am getting following error:

```
  Compiling 2 source files
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] /home/e01188/cm_data/grm/target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/src/groovy/grails/plugins/mongodb/ast/MongoDomainASTTransformation.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Transient
  [groovyc]  @ line 22, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Transient
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
  [groovyc] /home/e01188/cm_data/grm/target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/src/groovy/grails/plugins/mongodb/ast/MongoDomainASTTransformation.groovy: 12: unable to resolve class com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Embedded
  [groovyc]  @ line 12, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Embedded;
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
  [groovyc] /home/e01188/cm_data/grm/target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/src/groovy/grails/plugins/mongodb/ast/MongoDomainASTTransformation.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id. I have added the zip file in lib folder of the project. 
  [groovyc]  @ line 13, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
  [groovyc] /home/e01188/cm_data/grm/target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/src/groovy/grails/plugins/mongodb/ast/MongoDomainASTTransformation.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Version
  [groovyc]  @ line 14, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Version
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
  [groovyc] /home/e01188/cm_data/grm/target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/src/groovy/grails/plugins/mongodb/ast/MongoDomainASTTransformation.groovy: 25: unable to resolve class org.bson.types.ObjectId
  [groovyc]  @ line 25, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.bson.types.ObjectId
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
  [groovyc] /home/e01188/cm_data/grm/target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/src/groovy/grails/plugins/mongodb/ast/MongoDomainASTTransformation.groovy: 20: unable to resolve class com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity
  [groovyc]  @ line 20, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc]
| Compiling 2 source files.
| Error Error executing plugin mongodb-morphia-0.8.2 script: target/work/plugins/mongodb-morphia-0.8.2/scripts/_Install.groovy
```

Though there is not any version problem as i am using grails 2.4.3 and plugin `mongodb-morphia-0.8.2`. It is running smoothly on local system windows. But not working in linux platform. Both environments have same configuration with grails 2.4.3 and `mongodb-morphia-0.8.2`, but in linux the build is failed with above error. Please help, am stuck with it for two days.

One thing i noticed, `mongodb-morphia-ast.jar` exists in my target path on Windows but this jar is not visible in target on Linux. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well you already know your problem. How about fixing that jar first ?

Comment: that jar is not visible in `mongodb-morphia-0.8.2.zip`. it seems the code is compiled as jar and gets copied into target path. but that does not happen in linux for whatever reason.

Comment: why is that a zip file ? Isn't supposed to be jar file ? Can you show your ant config ?

Comment: hi..i could not resolve that issue with `mongodb-morphia-0.8.2.zip`..but now i am using `compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:3.0.1"` in BuildConfig.groovy class. Now the problem has been solved.